# Selecting unique random values from the third column of a an array in python

Tags: python, random

I have a 41000x3 numpy array that I call "sortedlist" in the function below. The third column has a bunch of values, some of which are duplicates, others which are not. I'd like to take a sample of unique values (no duplicates) from the third column, which is sortedlist[:,2]. I think I can do this easily with numpy.random.sample(sortedlist[:,2], sample_size). The problem is I'd like to return, not only those values, but all three columns where, in the last column, there are the randomly chosen values that I get from numpy.random.sample.

EDIT: By unique values I mean I want to choose random values which appear only once. So If I had an array:

```
array = [[0, 6, 2]
         [5, 3, 9]
         [3, 7, 1]
         [5, 3, 2]
         [3, 1, 1]
         [5, 2, 8]]
```

And I wanted to choose 4 values of the third column, I want to get something like new_array_1 out:

```
new_array_1 = [[5, 3, 9]
               [3, 7, 1]
               [5, 3, 2]
               [5, 2, 8]]
```

But I don't want something like new_array_2, where two values in the 3rd column are the same:

```
new_array_2 = [[5, 3, 9]
               [3, 7, 1]
               [5, 3, 2]
               [3, 1, 1]]
```

I have the code to choose random values but without the criterion that they shouldn't be duplicates in the third column.

```
samplesize = 100

rand_sortedlist = sortedlist[np.random.randint(len(sortedlist), size = sample_size),:]]
```

I'm trying to enforce this criterion by doing something like this

```
    array_index = where( array[:,2] == sample(SelectionWeight, sample_size) )
```

But I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I'd like to take a sample of unique values **(no duplicates)**".  Do you mean you want to exclude any values from the sampling if they appear more than once?  Or you want to sample from a list in which all elements are unique?  Or you want to sample without replacement, so the randomly sampled values are never duplicates?  Or some combination?  Some sample data would help.

Comment: Does the third column contain all numbers from 0 or 1 to the maximum, with some duplicates, or are there gaps in the sequence too?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a clever numpythonic way to do this that doesn't involve multiple passes over the data.  (Sometimes numpy is so much faster than pure Python that's still the fastest way to go, but it never feels right.)

In pure Python, I'd do something like

```
def draw_unique(vec, n):
    # group indices by value
    d = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(vec):
        d.setdefault(x, []).append(i)

    drawn = [random.choice(d[k]) for k in random.sample(d, n)]        
    return drawn
```

which would give

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (41000, 3))
>>> drawn = draw_unique(a[:,2], 3)
>>> drawn
[4219, 6745, 25670]
>>> a[drawn]
array([[5, 6, 0],
       [8, 8, 1],
       [5, 8, 3]])
```

I can think of some tricks with `np.bincount` and `scipy.stats.rankdata` but they hurt my head, and there always winds up being one step at the end I can't see how to vectorize.. and if I'm not vectorizing the whole thing I might as well use the above which at least is simple.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do what you want. Note that the running time will almost certainly be dominated by whatever method you use to generate your random numbers. (An exception is if the dataset is gigantic but you only need a small number of rows, in which case very few random numbers need to be drawn.) So I'm not sure this will run much faster than a pure python method would.

```
# arrayify your list of lists
# please don't use `array` as a variable name!
a = np.asarray(arry)

# sort the list ... always the first step for efficiency
a2 = a[np.argsort(a[:, 2])]

# identify rows that are duplicates (3rd column is non-increasing)
# Note this has length one less than a2
duplicate_rows = np.diff(a2[:, 2]) == 0)

# if duplicate_rows[N], then we want to remove row N and N+1
keep_mask = np.ones(length(a2), dtype=np.bool) # all True
keep_mask[duplicate_rows] = 0 # remove row N
keep_mask[1:][duplicate_rows] = 0 # remove row N + 1

# now actually slice the array
a3 = a2[keep_mask]

# select rows from a3 using your preferred random number generator
# I actually prefer `random` over numpy.random for sampling w/o replacement
import random
result = a3[random.sample(xrange(len(a3)), DESIRED_NUMBER_OF_ROWS)]
```